# How can I remove the first 30 second of 40 min video and add watermark also doing bulk using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, mp4

I was able to add watermark to multiple video using

```
for %%a in ("*.ts") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i  logoCopy.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

And now I'm trying to cut the first 30 second of the video and add watermark at the same time, I was able to cut the first 3o seconds using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 00:00:20 -map 0 -codec copy output.ts
```

Any one can help me combine the seouncd command to the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for %%a in ("*.ts") do ffmpeg -ss 30 -i "%%a" -i  logoCopy.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: it worked without any problem, thank you so much I really appreciate your help.